# Does the concept of connective constant make sense for any tiling of the plane?

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, random-walks, conformal-geometry, percolation

First let me define what is the "connective constant" of a two dimensional lattice. 
Let $c_{n}$ denote the number of $n$ step self-avoiding walks starting from a fixed origin point in the lattice. Then the limit (which can be shown to exist) 
$$ \mu := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } c_{n}^{\frac{1}{n}} $$
is the connective constant of the lattice.

My question is the following: does this definition also make sense on any periodic 
tiling of the plane? To clarify the difference, a lattice is a discrete 
subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So I think a lattice does give a tiling of 
the plane, but not the other way round.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ It seems from the comments I received that 
$\mu$ does make sense for any 
tiling. Is there any reason why $\mu$ has 
been studied only for a lattice and not for other tilings? Is there 
a reason why this is a "natural" question for lattices 
and an "artificial" question for other tilings.

Of course I could be wrong, i.e. this question has been studied for other 
lattices. In which case can someone point out any reference for 
this?  Presently $\mu$ is known for the Hexagonal 
Lattice (Smirnov) and conjectured for a few other lattices. I am looking 
for conjectures/numerical simulations for tilings that are not lattices.

For simplicity I was talking about $2$ dimensions, 
but the question makes sense in any dimension.

Comment: Could you describe explicitly an example of a tiling of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $4g$-gon with $g>1$? (I assume the tiles should be convex and congruent, but I could be wrong.)

Comment: I think I was mistaken; I can't really think of a tiling of R^2 even for an 8-gon. I do want the tiling to be congruent.

Comment: Then the only tilings you can have are by polygons with at most six sides, and if you want the tiles to be parallel translates of each other (rotations not allowed), then triangles and pentagons are out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind, but the question probably makes perfectly good sense for non-congruent tilings of the plane - whether periodic or not. I'm sure you could make a definition of $\mu$ that would work for any periodic tiling of the plane. I would be very confident that it would also work for aperiodic tilings such as the Penrose tiling also (without having any details in mind).

Comment: What you are saying seems to make perfect sense. The reason I asked this question is, it seems all the conjectures or numerical simulations done so far are for Lattices. Is there any particular reason why only Lattices have been studied?

Comment: @Kuperberg: What are the possible tilings I can have if I do not require the second condition (i.e. rotations are allowed)?

Comment: If rotations are allowed (all tiles convex and congruent), then there is a great variety of possible tilings. The problem of classifying all of them is still open. However, it seems that for your purpose the tiles need not even be congruent, but then the assumption of uniformity seems reasonable: there should be an upper bound on their diameters and a positive lower bound on their areas. Without this assumption $\mu$ could be undefined or infinite.

Comment: @Kuperberg: So calculating $\mu$ for other tilings is at least a meaningful question. I was just wondering why this has not been studied by others (because apriori it seems like a "natural" question to me and also something others are likely to have thought about).

Comment: Yes, your question is meaningful and natural. But it should not be too surprising if it has not been studied before - this happens quite often. A new discovery often leads to many new questions. I guess there are more such questions than all mathematicians in the world can handle or even think about. By the way, if you're interested in tilings, I recommend *"Tilings and Patterns"* (1987) - a great book by Grünbaum and Shephard.

Comment: I think the answer is probably yes for periodic and quasiperiodic in the sense of cut-and-project (eg Penrose).  But for others, the limit may not exist.  Consider rectangular tiles $1\times 1$ and $1\times 10$.  Any arrangement of vertical strips of width 1 is a tiling, but you could probably find a pathological choice of tiles for which the quantity oscillates and doesn't converge.

Comment: @Carl: My question was primarily for periodic tilings. Otherwise it is quite conceivable that $\mu$ doesn't exist.